# Create link/button to create new post using specific template

Tags: menus, templates

I created a custom template.
Via New > Post I can select the template manually.

In order to have an easy handling for users I want to create a button or link in wordpress menu to create a new post based on this dedicated template directly. How can I achieve that?

Is it also possible to automatically set a specific category for this new post?

thanks

Comment: Hello sunlight!   
Have you tried with a plugin?  
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/

Comment: This plugin simply duplicate an existing post...